# Storm Log File/File Directory: Where is it?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, apache-storm

I want to change the log file directory for storm and my own log(s)

I am working on localcluster, I have written simple code and run it from ide(IntelliJ), and it runs correctly, and shows the logs also.

I have decided to slf4j for my own log(s), and i have seen that storm uses this dependency internally:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Therefore I have decided to use slf4j with log4j binding.

Here is my dependencies:(Where slf4j version is 1.7.25)

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>compiled</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the my log4j.properties (I have create this file under the resources)

Note that: I have also tried to full file path instead of reference. Does not work

```
# Root logger option
  log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy:MM:dd         
HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5p %c %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=Log4jFiles/lcf4j.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5p %c %m%n
```

Here is picture, might help:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFAj8.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it seems that you probably have another log4j.properties file somewhere in your classpath which is being used instead of this one. Sometimes it can be included in jar files.

One possible solution would be to exclude the logging dependency of storm and provide your own logging dependencies and log4j.properties

Comment: Yes, i though that. When i exclude, it works, but i want to override this log4j.properties to my log4j.properties without exclusion. Because when when i tried to exclude, i experienced some error (log4j version conflict)

Comment: Add this to the  the storm.yaml at the supervisor machine node: 
worker.childopts: "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties " 
then I restart supervisor
after that it should start using your log4j instead of that of storm

Comment: if i work on production mode, i could try, but i am working on local mode, and run the code from ide.

Comment: storm 0.10.x switched to using log4j2 instead of logback,Storm just searches the log4j2.xml file under classpath.Since It is a maven project, you can put it under src/main/resource and override it